# foreach into a table

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I have a table with some data, that the users can updated it and i need that each new entry appears in another row.

And i have tried this:

```
 var equipsSplit = row.nomeEquipamentos;
 string[] equips = equipsSplit.Split(new Char[] { ';' });
```

Then on the table i've tried:

```
 <table>
   <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Nome Equipamentos</th>
           <th>Nº serie</th>
           <th>Opção</th>
           <th>Ação 1</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      @foreach (var valueEquips in equips){
        <tr>
          <td>@valueEquips</td>
        </tr>
      }
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

This works to this column, each data appears in a different row, but i need to create the same thing to the other columns, and i can't get how to put it all together in the table. I think that this might be simple but i can't reach it alone.

Hope that you guys can understand what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a friend explain me and it worked this is what we get:

We had to create a class.

```
public class Equipamento
{
public Equipamento()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}

public string Nome
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string Serial
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string Opcao1
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string Opcao2
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

}

Then we created a List.

```
@{
                                List<Equipamento> lst = new List<Equipamento>();
                                foreach (var valueEquips in equips){
                                    Equipamento eq = new Equipamento();
                                    eq.Nome = valueEquips;
                                    lst.Add(eq);
                                }

                                int countSerials = 0;
                                while (countSerials < lst.Count)
                                { 
                                    foreach (var valuenSerie in nSerie)
                                    {
                                        lst.ElementAt(countSerials).Serial = valuenSerie;
                                        ++countSerials;
                                    }
                                }

                                int countAccao1 = 0;
                                while (countAccao1 < lst.Count)
                                {
                                    foreach (var valueAccao1 in equipAccao1)
                                    {
                                        lst.ElementAt(countAccao1).Opcao1 = valueAccao1;
                                        ++countAccao1;
                                    }
                                }

                                int countAccao2 = 0;
                                while (countAccao2 < lst.Count)
                                {
                                    foreach (var valueAccao2 in equipAccao2)
                                    {
                                        lst.ElementAt(countAccao2).Opcao2 = valueAccao2;
                                        ++countAccao2;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
```

And put a foreach of the list in the table:

```
<table>
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Nome</th>
                                                        <th>Nº serie</th>
                                                        <th>Opção</th>
                                                        <th>Ação 1</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody> 
                                                        @foreach (var item in lst){
                                                          <tr>
                                                              <td>@item.Nome</td>
                                                              <td>@item.Serial</td>
                                                              <td>@item.Opcao1</td>
                                                              <td>@item.Opcao2</td>
                                                           </tr>
                                                         }   
                                                </tbody>
                             </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split up the array like this:

```
<table>
   <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Nome Equipamentos</th>
           <th>Nº serie</th>
           <th>Opção</th>
           <th>Ação 1</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
      @foreach (var valueEquips in equips){
          <td>@valueEquips</td>
      }
      </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: I think i didn't explain my question correctly. But thanks for your effort mate +1. I already got the solution, will post it here.